# Groovy 2.5.0 gives noclassdeffounderror for methodcalltransformation

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, spock

When I upgrade my project from Groovy 2.4.* to Groovy 2.5.0, it gives noclassdeffounderror for org/codehaus/groovy/ast/methodcalltransformation
when compiling using Gradle.

It works fine in Groovy 2.4.

Posting the whole exception here:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/ast/MethodCallTransformation
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler$1.<init>(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:117)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:117)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerRunnable.run(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:87)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:46)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:30)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.MethodCallTransformation
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: It seems that every groovy 2.5 release jar after 2.5.0-beta-2 is missing the MethodCallTransformation class. If you change :2.5.0 to :2.5.0-beta-2 that should solve your immediate problem and give you time to investigate whether this is a bug in gradle (failure to support the most recent release) or a bug in groovy (accidentally dropping an AST class from the build).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you also used Spring Boot, maybe the following workaround will help

Reference: [spring-boot issue #13444: Allow usage of Groovy 2.5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13444)

I used Gradle 4.8 and Spring Boot 1.5.14, and got the same NoClassDefFoundError after upgraded Groovy from 2.4.15 to 2.5.0.

After I do what the issue suggests, it builds successfully and also runs well,

1. Add `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin to `build.gradle`

   (I use Spring Boot 1.5 myself, Spring Boot 2 should also work well)

   ```
   plugins {
       id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.14.RELEASE'
       id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.5.RELEASE'
   }
   ```
2. set `groovy.version` to `2.5.0`

   ```
   ext['groovy.version'] = '2.5.0'
   ```
3. build and enjoy groovy 2.5! :)

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring Boot.   I just did #2 and it fixed my problem.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helps. :)

Comment: For Maven users just add `<groovy.version>X.X.X</groovy.version>` to the properties section of the `pom.xml` where X.X.X is the groovy version installed.

Comment: where in build.gradle do you add `ext['groovy.version'] = '2.5.0'`? the documentation doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon You can check this example project.

https://github.com/christoph-frick/springboot-vs-groovy25/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: If you're using a new version of Gradle you could just apply the plugin at the top of the build file by adding: `apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'` then set the `groovy.version` as you did.

Comment: Where do you set: ext['groovy.version'] = '2.5.0'?

Comment: @Thom just in build.gradle. like https://github.com/christoph-frick/springboot-vs-groovy25/blob/master/build.gradle#L26